# brew install julia LTS

Tags: macos, julia, homebrew

I accidentally installed Julia 1.8 using `brew install julia`, and I'd prefer to have julia 1.7 or the LTS. Is there a way to install the LTS using brew, or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: `brew uninstall julia` ??

Comment: @Luuk, That just gets rid of Julia, it doesn't help me get the LTS. I've since installed the LTS manually, after using `brew uninstall julia`.

Comment: `brew install homebrew/cask-versions/julia-lts`  After this using `julia-lts --version`, returns "1.6.7", and that seems to be the current LTS version (see: https://julialang.org/downloads/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the LTS version using: `brew install homebrew/cask-versions/julia-lts`

```
% brew search julia
==> Formulae
julia ✔                                                         juliaup                                                         julius

==> Casks
julia                                                           julia-lts ✔                                                     julia-nightly
% julia --version
julia version 1.8.1
% julia-lts --version
julia version 1.6.7
```